# Explain this line of code

Tags: c++

can someone explain when this line of code ends ? :

```
void constituteSubsequence(int i){
    if( Pred[i] + 1) constituteSubsequence(Pred[i]);
    cout << a[i] << " ";
}
```

In this program that calculate the longest increasing subsequence :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Pred[1000]; //Pred is previous.
int a[1000], v[1000], n, imax;
void read() {
    cout << " n = ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << " Sequence: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}
void constituteSubsequence(int i) {
    if (Pred[i] + 1) constituteSubsequence(Pred[i]);
    cout << a[i] << " ";
}
void calculate() {
    int i, j;
    v[0] = 1;
    imax = 0;
    Pred[0] = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        v[i] = 1;
        Pred[i] = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[i] && v[j] + 1 > v[i]) {
                v[i] = v[j] + 1;
                Pred[i] = j;
            }
            if (v[i] > v[imax]) {
                imax = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
void write() {
    cout << " Longest Increasing Subsequence : ";
    constituteSubsequence(imax);
    cout << endl << " Length: " << v[imax];
}
int main() {
    read();
    calculate();
    write();
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this code,it compiles and works as expected,but how does that condition repeat itself after it found a 0 value (false) and it print cout << a[i] ? .And when does it stop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain what this line of code does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657778/explain-what-this-line-of-code-does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ an integer expression can be treated as a Boolean. For example, in the context of `if` statement `Pred[i] + 1` means `(Pred[i] + 1) != 0`

This provides the answer to your question: the chain of recursive invocations is going to end when `Pred[i]` is `-1`. Of course, an easier to read way to express the same condition would be with the `!=` operator:

```
if( Pred[i] != -1) {
    constituteSubsequence(Pred[i]);
}
```

Comment: But how does it prints all the numbers in the longest increasing subsequence if it stops after Pred[i] is -1 ?